# Encoding hour and minute without date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

`datetime` is a pointer to a specific time at a specific date. I aggregated data over hours, how do I represent the index? For example:

```py
from pandas import Timestamp, Series

s = Series({
     Timestamp('2023-09-29 16:04:00'): 27.23,
     Timestamp('2023-09-29 16:03:00'): 27.333,
     Timestamp('2023-09-29 16:02:00'): 26.691,
     Timestamp('2023-09-29 16:01:00'): 27.23,
     Timestamp('2023-09-28 16:04:00'): 27.23,
     Timestamp('2023-09-28 16:03:00'): 27.23,
     Timestamp('2023-09-28 16:02:00'): 27.23,
     Timestamp('2023-09-28 16:01:00'): 27.23,
     Timestamp('2023-09-29 15:59:00'): 27.225,
     Timestamp('2023-09-29 15:58:00'): 27.235,
     Timestamp('2023-09-29 15:57:00'): 27.215,
     Timestamp('2023-09-29 15:56:00'): 27.22,
     Timestamp('2023-09-28 15:59:00'): 27.25,
     Timestamp('2023-09-28 15:58:00'): 27.295,
     Timestamp('2023-09-28 15:57:00'): 27.32,
     Timestamp('2023-09-28 15:56:00'): 27.31}
)

s_grouped = s.groupby([s.index.hour, s.index.minute]).mean()
print(s_grouped)
print(s_grouped.index)
```

```
15  56    27.2650
    57    27.2675
    58    27.2650
    59    27.2375
16  1     27.2300
    2     26.9605
    3     27.2815
    4     27.2300
dtype: float64

MultiIndex([(15, 56),
            (15, 57),
            (15, 58),
            (15, 59),
            (16,  1),
            (16,  2),
            (16,  3),
            (16,  4)],
           )
```

Is there a way to have a time-index so I can do `s['10:00:'11:00']`? I can convert integer-based MultiIndex to datetime by prepending a date (`s_grouped.index.map(lambda x: f'1970-01-01 {x[0]}:{x[1]}')`), but that is not usable in all cases (`s_grouped['10:00':'11:00']` for example). Plotting that I get `01-01 10`, `01-01 11` instead of `10:00`, `11:00` and have to manually format labels.

Comment: does `s.reset_index().groupby([s.index.hour, s.index.minute]).mean().set_index('index')` help?

Comment: Aggregating the index? That doesn't usually work. Not to mention that your code errors on the example I gave.
Also, the main point is about having "dateless datetime".

Comment: I admit it's hacky, but you could just set all observations to the same date (like 1.1.1970).

Comment: @EliasStrehle that's what I did. It does the job in my specific case, but leaves me wondering if maybe there is a more universal approach.

Comment: A time-only index is a different concept than a datetime index. Datetime is linear and unbounded; time-only is either circular instead of linear (23:59 plus one minute gets you back to 00:00) or bounded (23:59 plus one minute is out of bounds). This means that, for example, the concept of a rolling window would work differently with a time-only index. So I think a time-only index could not work out of the box with datetime-index tools.

Answer (score 1):

```
 pd.to_datetime(s_grouped.index.map(lambda x: x[0]*3600 + x[1]*60),
               unit = 's').strftime('%H:%M')

Index(['15:56', '15:57', '15:58', '15:59', '16:01', '16:02', '16:03', '16:04'], dtype='object')
```

You cannot have a dateless time. Your best option is to either use timedelta or have:

```
pd.to_datetime(s_grouped.index.map(lambda x: x[0]*3600 + x[1]*60), unit = 's')
DatetimeIndex(['1970-01-01 15:56:00', '1970-01-01 15:57:00',
               '1970-01-01 15:58:00', '1970-01-01 15:59:00',
               '1970-01-01 16:01:00', '1970-01-01 16:02:00',
               '1970-01-01 16:03:00', '1970-01-01 16:04:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize pandas treats strings as time so liberally. Or is it just string indexing? However, this still doesn't allow to use things like `rolling`.

Comment: @Physmatik you cannot have a dateless time. If you need the date, ten no need to format to string.

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there a way to have a time-index so that we can, e.g. `s['10:00:'11:00']`?*

What about using [`between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between_time.html) ?

```
s.between_time("15:59", "16:03")

2023-09-29 16:03:00   27.3330
2023-09-29 16:02:00   26.6910
2023-09-29 16:01:00   27.2300
2023-09-28 16:03:00   27.2300
2023-09-28 16:02:00   27.2300
2023-09-28 16:01:00   27.2300
2023-09-29 15:59:00   27.2250
2023-09-28 15:59:00   27.2500
dtype: float64
```

If needed, you can perform [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) operations and [`plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.html) the result :

```
(
    s.between_time("15:59", "16:03")
        .sort_index().rolling("2T").mean()
        .rename(lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M"))
        .plot()
)
```

[image]